# How to return only collection of certain entries from a complex type after query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a complex type defined something like this:

```
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Fax { get; set; }

    public string Email{ get; set; }
```

and some more fields, and the name of the class in Business.

The point is that I have a query, where I want to find only certain businesses, and then I want to return all those businesses' e-mail addresses in an `IEnumerable<string>`. It is important that I store them in `IEnumerable<string>`.

I have my query defined like this:

```
var list = db.Businesses.Where(b => b.Description.ToLower() == "electrics" && b.City.ToLower() == "new york");
```

which return `IEnumerable<Business>`, the point is as I said, I want to take their e-mail address only. How can I do it?

Comment: Where did you learn about the `Where` statement? The next paragraph should be about the `Select` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project the businesses into an `IEnumerable` that contains only the email strings using the LINQ `Select` extension method:

```
var list = db.Businesses.Where(b => b.Description.ToLower() == "electrics" && b.City.ToLower() == "new york").Select(b=>b.Email);
```